# Did the idea of motion illusion exist in medieval or islamic art?

Tags: middle-ages, islam, art

Motion illusion by colors is like in the given picture

[image]

My inquiry is about the implementation of the heavy use of colors to form patterns and designs on the walls in medieval Christian and Islamic art. Did they use such art patterns anywhere? I would like to see the earliest examples of optical illusions with colors. It is also okay if examples are from other cultures such as Indian, Chinese history, etc.

Comment: First reaction is that a more likely explanation for that is [iconoclasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconoclasm), but its a good question.

Comment: Roman example: http://www.getty.edu/art/collection/objects/6576/unknown-maker-mosaic-floor-with-head-of-medusa-roman-about-115-150/

Comment: This can be a good [read](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_aftereffect) on this topic.

Comment: View the interiors of The Alcazar in Seville, as well as The Alhambra in Granada